# organizing phone number using regular expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

There are two strings like

```
'my phone number is 010-1111-1456'
'my house address is 123-456'
```

my code:

```
text1 = 'my phone number is 010-1111-1456'
text2 = 'my house address is 123-456'
print(re.search('[0-9]+[-]+[0-9]+[^-]', text1)) 
print(re.search('[0-9]+[-]+[0-9]+[^-]', text2))
```

How the output should be like:

```
<re.Match object; span=(20, 27), match='123-456'>
```

My output:

```
<re.Match object; span=(19, 27), match='010-1111'>   
<re.Match object; span=(20, 27), match='123-456'>
```

My problem: i want to print only the second one like

```
<re.Match object; span=(20, 27), match='123-456'>
```

how can i get this code right?

Comment: remove or comment this line print(re.search('[0-9]+[-]+[0-9]+[^-]', text1))

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you only want to match two batches of numbers? How about adding numbers also into the second [^-]?

Comment: @new_be I think your regex is wrong. Try `print(re.search('[0-9]+[-]+[0-9]+^-', text1)) ` or `print(re.search('[0-9]+[-]+[0-9]+^[-]', text1)) `

Comment: Also you can use this site to test your regex https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want is `\d{3}\-\d{3}$`, depending on use-case, `(?:$|[^\d-])(\d{3}-\d{3})(?:$|[^\d-])` is an alternative. Use [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) to find the one that fits your usage please.

Answer (score 0):

Might not the best solution, but it searches good:

```
((\d)+\-){1,2}\d+
```

try to search already ready solutions, there're might be bunch of them